# RecordNotUnique Exception

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting an error like
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique Exception` in my `has_many` through association

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers_sellers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sellers, through: :customers_sellers
end 

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers_sellers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :customers, through: :customers_sellers
end 

class CustomersSeller < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :seller
end
```

While create customer for a particular seller, I'm getting an error at
`CustomersSeller.create()` line.

```
Error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique Exception
```

In my has_many through association.

Duplicate key violates unique constraint "customers_sellers_pkey".

Comment: The error means you already have this customer for this particular seller. Unique index prevents you from attempt to create duplicate.

Comment: I am creating new customer for a seller

Comment: You could inspect your logs to find out the INSERT query and its `customer_id` and `seller_id` values. Then do raw SQL SELECT query to the table with that values.

Comment: Please add more detail i.e. How you are creating customer for a particular seller?
Also put your logs here.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue:

```
    begin
          CustomersSeller.where(seller_id: @seller.id, customer_id: @customer.id).first_or_create(seller: @seller, customer: @customer, customer_name: @customer.try(:business_name), status: "Invited")
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
    retry
  end
```